# Updating WPF TextBox properties after setting Text

Tags: wpf, textbox

When setting the Text property of a WPF TextBox control, other properties that should also change (as a side effect) do not change.  In particular, I would like to check the value of the ExtentWidth property after setting Text, but it does not change.  I've tried calling UpdateLayout() to no avail.  In Windows.Forms, I would call DoEvents().

OK, here's some code.  I put this in the Window_Loaded() event handler. The problem is that textBox.ExtentWidth doesn't change when textBox.Text changes.  That doesn't really surprise me.  I figure I need to call something like textBox.UpdateLayout() to make it recalculate ExtentWidth, but that didn't help.  ExtentWidth does vary depending on what I initialize textBox.Text to in the Window's constructor, but that doesn't help me.  I need to set several different Text values and get the corresponding ExtentWidth for each.

```
   string initText = textBox.Text;   // "textBox"
   double extentWidth = textBox.ExtentWidth; // 39.3

   textBox.Text = "short text";
   extentWidth = textBox.ExtentWidth;  // 39.3

   textBox.Text = "Long enough to make a difference, eh?";
   extentWidth = textBox.ExtentWidth;  // 39.3
```

Comment: What is the value you are getting, is it 0.0?

Comment: Please add some code to this so we can see what you are looking at.

Comment: ActualWidth gives you the actual width of a wpf control. but some code will help helping you :)

Comment: What do you mean under "setting"? After navigating from `TextBox` or on `TextChanged` event? ;)

Comment: OP here.  I added some code illustrate my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution to the specific problem of getting `TextBox.ExtentWidth` to change after setting Text.  Setting Text will raise the `LayoutUpdated` event, and you can get the new value of `ExtentWidth` in a handler for `LayoutUpdated`.

I used this fact to create a subclass of WPF `TextBox` that displays an ellipsis when the text is too long for the visible area.  I wrote a CodeProject article about it [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/TextBoxWithEllipsis.aspx).